# Inventory on Text based game

Tags: python

I'm learning python right now and so far I have been doing ok but my final project is stumping me. We have to create a text-based game where you can navigate to a few locations to collect items in your inventory before you can beat the final boss. I have the code for the navigation. I can travel from planet to planet with no problem. The issue I have is with the inventory. I need to be able to collect the light crytals in each room. Right now I've integrated the items to my dictionary, created an invetory list and created an if statement to print if the item is in the room but none of that is working. Only the navigation works. Any help would be appreciated. My full code is listed below.

```
#Leria Bailey simple navigation

#Dictionary linking planets and items in each desired room
planets = {
    'Home Planet': {'name': 'Home Planet', 'south': 'Yellow Planet', 'west': 'Red Planet', 'east': 'Grey Planet',
                    'text': 'You are in the Home Planet.'},

    'Red Planet': {'name': 'Red Planet', 'east': 'Home Planet', 'south': 'Orange Planet',
                   'text': 'You are in the Red Planet.','item':'Red Light Crystal'},

    'Orange Planet': {'name': 'Orange Planet', 'north': 'Red Planet', 'east': 'Yellow Planet',
                      'text': 'You are in the Orange Planet.','item':'Orange Light Crystal'},

    'Yellow Planet': {'name': 'Yellow Planet', 'west': 'Orange Planet', 'north': 'Home Planet', 'east': 'Indigo Planet',
                      'south': 'Green Planet',
                      'text': 'You are in the Yellow Planet.','item':'Yellow Light Crystal'},

    'Green Planet': {'name': 'Green Planet', 'north': 'Yellow Planet', 'east': 'Blue Planet',
                     'text': 'You are in the Green Planet.','item':'Green Light Crystal'},

    'Blue Planet': {'name': 'Blue Planet', 'north': 'Yellow Planet', 'east': 'Blue Planet',
                    'text': 'You are in the Blue Planet.','item':'Blue Light Crystal'},

    'Indigo Planet': {'name': 'Indigo Planet', 'south': 'Blue Planet', 'west': 'Yellow Planet', 'east': 'Violet Planet',
                      'text': 'You are in the Indigo Planet.','item':'Indigo Light Crystal'},

    'Violet Planet': {'name': 'Violet Planet', 'west': 'Indigo Planet', 'north': 'Grey Planet',
                      'text': 'You are in the Violet Planet.','item':'Violet Light Crystal'},

    'Grey Planet': {'name': 'Grey Planet', 'south': 'Violet Planet', 'west': 'Home Planet',
                    'text': 'You are in the Grey Planet.','item:Light Crystal','item':'Shadow King'},
}

#start Player in Home Planet
direction = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
current_room = planets['Home Planet']
show_instructions = "Enter north, south, east or west to explore different planets. Enter Exit to leave the game."

# inventory list to hold items and possible items
inventory = []
item = ['Red Light Crystal', 'Orange Light Crystal', 'Yellow Light Crystal', 'Green Light Crystal', 'Blue Light Crystal','Indigo Light Crystal', 'Violet Light Crystal', 'Shadow King']

#print game intr
print('----------------------------')
print("Light Hero Text Adventure Game!")
print("Collect 7 light crystals to win the game, or be defeated by the Shadow King.")
print("Let's get started!")
print('----------------------------')

#Planet navigation
while True:
    if current_room['name'] == 'Grey Planet':
        print('Congratulations! You have reached the Grey Planet and defeated the Shadow King!')
        break

    # display current location & Inventory
    print('You are in {}.'.format(current_room['name']))
    print('Your current inventory: {}\n'.format(inventory))                  
    if current_room['item']:
        print('Item in room: {}'.format(inventory.append(current_room['item'])))
        print('')                                                           


    # get user input
    print(show_instructions)
    command = input()
    print('----------------------------')

    # movement
    if command in direction:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = planets[current_room[command]]

        elif command == 'get item':                                  
            if current_room['item'] != 'none':
                Inventory['Item' + str(len(Inventory.keys()) + 1)] = current_room['item']
                # Inventory.append(current_room['item'])

                print("You acquired : ", current_room['item'])
                print(Inventory)
                current_room['item'] = 'none'
            else:                                                    
                print("No items to collect in this room")            

        else:
            # bad movement
            print('*** You cannot go that way. Please try again ***')
    # quit game
    elif command == 'exit':
        print('You have exited the game. Thanks for playing!')
        break
    # bad command
    else:
        print('*** Invalid input. Please try again ***')

#get Item
def get_item(current_room):
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]: #if statement
        return rooms[current_room]['item'] #return statement
    else:
        return 'This room has no item!' #return statement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following updates to make your code work

1. In the grey planet dictionary, replace 'item:Light Crystal' with 'item':'Light Crystal'
2. In the home planet dictionary, item is not defined but code is trying to access it. Either add 'item':'none' in the dictionary or use current_room.get('item','none') instead of current_room['item'].

Let me know in comments if you need more help.
Please vote this if it helps